# Variable resetting after each button clicked JS and Symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have radio buttons and I want to calculate display score at last on every correct answers. In following code table is database table, choice1, choice2, choice3, answer are options. I want to display the total score out of total question at last. Below is my javascript, the sum value in js is resetting every time the next button is clicked. How to save sum variable after each button is clicked.
Thank you

**Twig file**

```
{% set counter = 0 %}
    {% for table in entities %} 
        <form role="form">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="radio"name="choices" >{{ table.choice1 }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="radio" name="choices">{{ table.choice2 }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="radio" name="choices">{{ table.choice3 }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="radio"name="choices" >{{ table.answer }}</label>
            </div>
        {%  if counter==entitites|length %}
                <button onclick="submitanswer()" >Submit</button>
        {% else %}
           <li> <a onclick="myFunction()" href="{{ path('view', route_params | merge({ 'id': table.Id+1 })) }}">Next</a></li>
        {% endif %}
       </form>
            {% endif %}
            {% set counter = counter+1 %}
      {% endfor %}
```

**Javascript**

```
    {% block javascript %}
        <script>
            var choice, choices;
            var sum = 0;

            function myFunction() {
                choices=document.getElementsByName("choices");
                for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
                    if(choices[i].checked){
                        choice = choices[i].value;
                    }
                 }
                alert(choice);
                alert(choices[3].value);
                if(choice==choices[3].value){
                    sum += 1;
                alert(sum);
                }
                else{
                    alert(sum);
                }
                {#if(choice=={{ answer }}){#}
                  {##}
                {#}#}
                {#alert({{ entities[0].answer }});#}
                {#return sum;#}
              }   

            function submitanswer(){
                choices=document.getElementsByName("choices");
                for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
                    if(choices[i].checked){
                        choice = choices[i].value;
                    }
                }
                    if(choice==choices[3].value){
                    sum += 1;
                }
                alert(sum);
            }
            </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't think that plain javascript is the best way to do that - it would mean that you have to mark the correct answers somehow into the elements (or into the checking javascript) and those would then be visible for the users who know how to look for them from the page source (i.e. they could find the correct answers from reading the source code of the page). How are you currently processing the form submits for each of the forms?

Comment: i am currently using form submit to store all questions and answers on database. what should i use to calculate the scores its difficult using js and  twig

Comment: So, lets say you have 10 objects in your entities collection. Meaning that you would generate 10 separate forms in your view - with 10 separate submit buttons. So you saying that you already have some logic for storing the these submitted answers to your database? If you do - you can just calculate the correct answers on the server side and return that as a view parameter to be shown

Comment: Yes, the view part is all good. But while calculating the score for e.g i have sum variable on my js. when user clicks next button the sum variable is being reset on clicking the next button. This is my button for next question using get. 
 <a onclick="myFunction()" href="{{ path(view', route_params | merge({ 'id': table.questionId+1 })) }}">Next</a>

Comment: well, if you have a normal link (without ajax request) it is quite normal that your js variable gets reset with each link as it reloads the page. If you really want to make a js solution - you can modify your 'next' link clicks to ajax calls and thus save your progress in the client side for your calculations...Your original question still shows submit buttons in the forms and no next link described in the previous comment so it is somewhat hard to try to keep up how your solution really looks like. And again - why don't you calculate the result in controller and pass it to the view?